# Java/SQL find duplicates

Tags: java, database, jdbc, duplicates, derby

What is the best way to find and remove duplicated or similar records in the database?

Similar means same in some columns of database

I'm doing it now by 1 for_loop for current database/table rows, 1 for_loop for database rows from current to last, 1 for_loop for database columns and finally a switch for column type. Which takes some minutes

Comment: No way to answer without a specification of what "duplicated or similar" means.

Comment: hi @chrylis I have told what do I mean by similar. I mean 2 record be same in some of columns of database. and duplicate means these 2 record be same in all of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you considered sorting( on the columns you want)...and after that opening a cursor and deleting similiar resoureces.

Comment: hi @RAHUL-ROY ; I have tried. the problem is here that a _ResultSet_ created from SQL containing `order by` words will automatically become disable of updating.

Comment: dear @RAHUL I have done such a thing another place, I've made extra column as **row-number-2** and I've made `order by` sql... then created an array of duplications based on that **row-number-2** ... finally another sql without `order by` and update that from the created array... but as you see this is not an easy way... and also get time (both from me and computer! :) )

Comment: Hi @mhjstackoverflow:If you can add a column in database,Then it is quite easier..... add another column ( say row id increamental value) now. run belwo sql.
delete from table where
row_id not in ( select uniq row_id from table a,table b where(condition for similiaritylike a.X=b.X anda.Y=b.Y   )  )

Please let me know  if you face any trouble in this.

Comment: hi, i don't know. I have put up arrow, but cause I have less reputation is hidden. thanks again. (i'm working on your code)

Comment: Thanks for choosing as an answer.